# What's the Apache server's user's group name on Mac?

Tags: apache, macos, mercurial

What's Apache group on Mac (the www-data group on Debian)?

Comment: use staff  on osx instead www-data (Linux/Ubuntu)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess the user and group is _www and _www.